# Implicitly convert collection (HashSet) to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, casting

I have a simple abstract enumeration class:

```
public abstract class Enumeration<T> {

    protected readonly T _value;
    private static readonly HashSet<Enumeration<T>> _values
        = new HastSet<Enumeration<T>>();

    protected Enumeration(T value) {
        _value = value;
        _values.Add(this);
    }

}
```

Now I would like to have a method that returns every element in the HashSet, but not the HashSet itself ( -> as an IEnumerable).

But this doesn't work:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues() {
     return _values;
}
```

because I cannot implicitly convert `HashSet` to `IEnumerable<T>`, of course. The only way I can think of is looping through the HashSet and yielding every element, but I wonder if there's a way to do this automatically, like when you implicitly cast a list to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: You can do `_yourHashSet.AsEnumerable()`. BUT I'm not 100% sure, but it can provide duplicates removed by hashset

Comment: HashSet **is** enumerable. What is your exact problem? Why are you adding `this` to hashset `_values.Add(this);`?

Comment: @wudzik WHOOPS. My bad! I tried with AsEnumerable() but it didn't work because I can't convert IEnumerable<Enumeration<T>> to IEnumerable<T> - turned out I had to change the return value. I need sleep, obviously. :/

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Because it's an enumeration and I don't want to use reflection to acquire all defined fields. ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can implicitly convert `HashSet<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, because HashSet, like ewvery other generic collection type, implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

However, for obvious reasons, you cannot convert `HashSet<U>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, unless `U` is convertible to `T` (in which case you can use an implicit covariant conversion).

Your `HashSet` is (but probably should not be) a collection of `Enumeration<T>`, not `T`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues()
{
    return _values.Select(e => e._value);
}
```